# Reason why all DAG have more than one topological sort order

Tags: sorting, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I am wondering as to why all Directed Acyclic Graph have more than one topological sort order.

I have searched up google and saying most of it just breeze through the fact that they have at least one topo sort. But i am thinking along the lines of how a singly linked list is implemented :

A -> B -> C -> D

This might mean that there is only one way the toposort can technically go through - D, C, B, A...

However, it may be the case that that is not a directed acyclic graph but i am not sure how to refute the case  since it is directed (A to B, etc) , Acyclic (There are no cycles back to any start) Graph (it is technically a tree)..

Thank you so much for any clarifications provided !

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that all DAGs have more than one topological sort. Remember that we can construct a topological sort by removing vertices with no incoming edges in order.

Consider a DAG that contains a continuous path that connects all its vertices (Note that this path does not form a cycle, otherwise it won't be a DAG). We can start by removing a vertex with no incoming edge and repeat. We'll find that the topological sort has an edge between each consecutive pair of vertices. If we wanted to form another topological sort, we could have started by removing some other vertex with no incoming edge, but this would mean that there are at least 2 edges with no incoming edges and in that case, it would be impossible to start a path from one vertex and connect all others.

Since we started with a DAG having a path connecting all the vertices, we are met with a contradiction. Hence, it is proven that a DAG with a path connecting all the vertices will have a unique topological sort.